# UIToolbar slides up and UIView slides down in displayed view

Tags: iphone

UIButton from the `UIToolbar` on the `Mainviewcontroller` when displays `UIView`, `UIToolbar` slides up in the `View` displayed. From the `View` when `infobutton` is pressed to present modalviewcontroller and upon dismissal modalviewcontroller slides down.

`UIToolbar` and `Modalviewcontroller` both are behaving normal in the `Mainviewcontroller` i.e `UIToolbar`not sliding up and `Modalviewcontroller` not sliding down upon dismissal.

```
- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
{
   self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]autorelease]; 

  [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

   PageOneViewController *viewController = [[[PageOneViewController alloc] init]autorelease];

   [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

   [self.view addSubview:self.toolbar];

}
```

Any ideas why it is happening and what should i do to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved one issue out of these two

By adding this statement

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

removed the gap which was showing upon dismissal of the modalviewcontroller

Basically now displayviewsAction goes like this

```
- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
{
   self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]autorelease];

    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

   PageOneViewController *viewController = [[[PageOneViewController alloc] init]autorelease];

   [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];

   [self.view addSubview:toolbar];       
}
```

But still struggling with uitoolbar gap from the bottom when view is loaded. Any ideas how to solve the UIToolbar gap from the bottom of the view.